# Registering partially-closed generic type with ASP.NET Core Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection

Tags: c#, generics, dependency-injection, asp.net-core, .net-core

In an ASP.NET Core 1.1.2 web project, which depends on *Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection 1.1.1*, I'm trying to register a generic *FluentValidation* validator both with its implementation and with its interface. At runtime, during host building, I got following exception:

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.dll

Cannot instantiate implementation type 'MyProj.Shared.Api.WithUserCommandValidator`1[T]' for service type 'FluentValidation.IValidator`1[MyProj.Shared.Model.WithUser`1[T]]'.

   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceTable..ctor(IEnumerable`1 descriptors)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider..ctor(IEnumerable`1 serviceDescriptors, Boolean validateScopes)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceCollectionContainerBuilderExtensions.BuildServiceProvider(IServiceCollection services)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost.BuildApplication()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.WebHostBuilder.Build()
   at MyProj.Program.Main(String[] args) in X:\MySolution\src\MyProj\Program.cs:line 31
```

This is the (generic, non-abstract) validator class:

```cs
public class WithUserCommandValidator<TCommand> : AbstractValidator<WithUser<TCommand>>
    where TCommand : ICommand
{
    public WithUserCommandValidator(IValidator<TCommand> commandValidator)
    {
        RuleFor(cmd => cmd).NotNull();

        RuleFor(cmd => cmd.UserId).NotEqual(Guid.Empty);

        RuleFor(cmd => cmd.Content).NotNull()
            .SetValidator(commandValidator);
    }
}
```

(not sure is important to show `WithUser<T>` class, it just holds a `Guid UserId` and a `T Content`).

Registration happens like so:

```cs
someInterface = typeof(FluentValidation.IValidator<WithUser<>>);
someImplementation = typeof(Shared.Api.WithUserCommandValidator<>);

// this is for top-level command validators, injected by interface
services.AddScoped(someInterface, someImplementation);

// this is for nested validators, injected by implementation
services.AddScoped(someImplementation);
```

and at runtime those variables hold:

```
+ someInterface  {FluentValidation.IValidator`1[MyProj.Shared.Model.WithUser`1[TCommand]]}  System.Type {System.RuntimeType}
+ someImplementation  {MyProj.Shared.Api.WithUserCommandValidator`1[TCommand]}  System.Type {System.RuntimeType}
```

which seems correct.

I've looked around for similar problems and questions on SO as well, but they're not really related, as they were about generic implementation, while this is a concrete one.

I've stepped through *DependencyInjection* module code, and exception is thrown [here](https://github.com/aspnet/DependencyInjection/blob/rel/1.1.1/src/Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection/ServiceLookup/ServiceTable.cs#L69). For some reason, `serviceTypeInfo.IsGenericTypeDefinition` returns *false* (shouldn't that be *true*, as the interface type is generic?) and so the else-branch is taken. There, instead, the implementation type return *true* to `implementationTypeInfo.IsGenericTypeDefinition`, so there you have the exception.

Runtime values are:

```
+ serviceTypeInfo {FluentValidation.IValidator`1[MyProj.Shared.Model.WithUser`1[TCommand]]} System.Reflection.TypeInfo {System.RuntimeType}
+ implementationTypeInfo {MyProj.Shared.Api.WithUserCommandValidator`1[TCommand]}   System.Reflection.TypeInfo {System.RuntimeType}
```

While fiddling, I tried registering only the implementation, without also registering interface+implementation, and that exception goes away. But I'd like to inject the interface, if possible, not the implementation.

What am I doing wrong? TA

Comment: Some more details: .NET Core code checks `serviceTypeInfo.IsGenericTypeDefinition`, which is false, while instead `serviceTypeInfo.IsGenericType` is true. But I have no info on what does the former mean.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What you are trying to do is to map a partially closed type (namely `IValidator<WithUser<T>>`), which is something that is not supported by .NET Core's DI container. When it comes to generic types, the .NET Core container is a very minimalistic, simplistic implementation. It is unable to handle things like:

- generic type constraints
- partially closed types
- implementations with less generic type arguments than the abstraction
- implementations with generic type arguments in a different order than the abstraction
- having generic type arguments being nested as part of a type argument of the partially closed abstraction (which is your exact case)
- [Curiously recurring template pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern)

If you require this behavior *and* want to keep continuing to use the built-in container for this, you will have to register each closed implementation by hand:

```
AddScoped(typeof(IValidator<WithUser<Cmd1>>),typeof(WithUserCommandValidator<Cmd1>));
AddScoped(typeof(IValidator<WithUser<Cmd2>>),typeof(WithUserCommandValidator<Cmd2>));
AddScoped(typeof(IValidator<WithUser<Cmd3>>),typeof(WithUserCommandValidator<Cmd3>));
// etc
```

If this is leads to an unmaintainable Composition Root, you should pick a different container. The only DI Container that I know actually fully supports these kinds of generic designs is [Simple Injector](https://simpleinjector.org/).

With Simple Injector, you can simply do the following registration:

```
container.Register(
    typeof(IValidator<>),
    typeof(WithUserCommandValidator<>),
    Lifestyle.Scoped);
```

Comment: I see. Was not aware of those specific limitations. Thanks

Comment: Autofac is also able to register these open types: http://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/register/registration.html#open-generic-components. We rely heavily on this feature because of our use of Command and Query patterns.