# .NET Dependency Injection and Open Generics

Tags: .net, dependency-injection

Trying to migrate from AutoFac to .NET DI (in an quite early stage of the project...)

I have troubles registering an open generic:

```
services.AddScoped(typeof(IDeviceRepository<>), typeof(DeviceRepository<>));
```

I get this exception when calling

> ServiceProvider = ServiceCollection.BuildServiceProvider();

```
System.ArgumentException: Cannot instantiate implementation type 'Core.Repositories.DeviceRepository`1[T]' for service type 'Core.Repositories.Interfaces.IRepository`1[T]'.
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteFactory.Populate()
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteFactory..ctor(ICollection`1 descriptors)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider..ctor(ICollection`1 serviceDescriptors, ServiceProviderOptions options)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceCollectionContainerBuilderExtensions.BuildServiceProvider(IServiceCollection services, ServiceProviderOptions options)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceCollectionContainerBuilderExtensions.BuildServiceProvider(IServiceCollection services)
   at Avalonia.GUI.App.OnFrameworkInitializationCompleted() in C:\Users\jjjjjjjjjjjjjj\Programming\Avalonia.GUI\App.axaml.cs:line 30
   at Avalonia.Controls.AppBuilderBase`1.Setup() in /_/src/Avalonia.Controls/AppBuilderBase.cs:line 312
   at Avalonia.Controls.AppBuilderBase`1.SetupWithLifetime(IApplicationLifetime lifetime) in /_/src/Avalonia.Controls/AppBuilderBase.cs:line 179
   at Avalonia.ClassicDesktopStyleApplicationLifetimeExtensions.StartWithClassicDesktopLifetime[T](T builder, String[] args, ShutdownMode shutdownMode) in /_/src/Avalonia.Controls/ApplicationLifetimes/ClassicDesktopStyleApplicationLifetime.cs:line 208
   at Avalonia.GUI.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Users\jjjjjjjjjj\Programming\Avalonia.GUI\Program.cs:line 12
```

I am wondering why it calls for an 'IRepository'. That is the base interface of an 'IDeviceRepository'.

```
public class DeviceRepository<T> : RepositoryBase<T>, IDeviceRepository<T>
        where T : class, IDevice
```

and

```
public interface IDeviceRepository<T> : IRepository<T> where T : class, IDevice
```

RepositoryBase is abstract and implements IRepository.
I am also doing something like the following, but i am not sure if that is the problem...

```
    var typesWithInterface = Assembly.Load(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name!)
        .GetTypes()
        .Where(t => GetMatchingInterface(t) is not null);
```

to automatically register everything where my name convention of Type is IType. Also tried to skip abstract types but to no avail.

**Edit**: I narrowed it down a bit. It was indeed a problem with the last snippet. I called GetInterfaces() on all the typesWithInterface later on, resulting in also getting the base interface of course.
Now, i still have the same error as i mentioned earlier, but with IDeviceRepository instead of IRepository

**Edit2:**
[Registering partially-closed generic type with ASP.NET Core Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44987331/registering-partially-closed-generic-type-with-asp-net-core-microsoft-extensions)
This answer is still valid i guess? :(

Comment: I think it doesn't like the fact that `RepositoryBase` is abstract.

Comment: @CristianRusanu But in general, i don't want to instantiate that so i don't understand why that should be a problem?

Comment: Yes, you are right. It may not be that. It doesn't know how to "close" IDevice. The default DI in .net Core has some limitations.

Comment: When you register an implementation, you're telling it *exactly* which type to create. It can't create an instance of an abstract type. Not only is that impossible, but imagine if it was possible. There could be multiple classes that inherit from the abstract type. Which one would it create? Or, what if nothing inherits from the abstract class? It can't and won't guess. It can only create the type you tell it to create. The composition root is the place where concrete decisions are made.

Comment: But that still is the case with that example if i dont mix anything up. I don't want to instantiate an abstract type, just an open generic. My first version of the post indeed tried to do that, but i corrected it in the first edit.
Autofac had the possibility to inject open generics though, but my second edit (and i think that is also the case here) shows that .NET DI doesnt do that unfortuantely

Comment: Please post the relevant code of `Avalonia.GUI.App.OnFrameworkInitializationCompleted` especially around line `30`.